# I can't see the picture I have added on my layout activity

Tags: android

Please I would need your help to figure out, why these code lines doesn't add an imageView on my playSpace (FrameLayout) when I run it. I just get the playSpace layout without images. What I'm doing wrong ?

//java code

package com.code123.en.createObj;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ViewGroup playSpace;
    private float scale;
    private Random randomNumber = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        playSpace= (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.playSpace);
    }

    private void showAFly()
    {
        scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        int width= playSpace.getWidth();
        int height = playSpace.getHeight();

        int fly_width = Math.round(scale*50);
        int fly_height = Math.round(scale*42);

        int left= randomNumber.nextInt(width- fly_width);
        int top= randomNumber.nextInt(height- fly_height);

        ImageView fly = new ImageView(this);
        fly.setImageResource(R.drawable.fly);
        fly.setOnClickListener(this);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new  FrameLayout.LayoutParams(fly_width,fly_height);
        params.leftMargin = left;
        params.topMargin = top;
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP + Gravity.LEFT;
        playSpace.addView(fly,params);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doSomething();
    }
```

//activity_main.xml code lines 
//It works fine manually

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/playSpace"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/fly" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the layout parameters for the `ImageView` before adding the view to the `Viewgroup`.

```
fly.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I have now called my method into my onCreate-method but it still doesn't work. The app stops directly when I run it and I also set the layout parameters for the ImageView before adding the view to the Viewgroup just like you suggest it

Comment: Can u post the crash log?

Comment: part 1: 09-29 19:20:21.055 23395-23395/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-29 19:20:21.055 23395-23395/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.code123.en.createObj; PID: 23395
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.code123.en.createObj;/com.code123.en.createObj;.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: -100
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275)

Comment: part2: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

Comment: part3:at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: -100
        at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
        at com.code123.en.createObj.MainActivity.showAFly(MainActivity.java:39)
        at com.code123.en.createObj.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)

Comment: part4: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)

Comment: last part: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Comment: Sorry, I know that it is not good readable, but I can't post more than 585 characteres by commenting. Is there a better way to post my logcat ?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling showAFly()?

Try calling it after

```
playSpace= (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.playSpace);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I have now called my showAFly()-method into my onCreate()-method but it still doesn't work. The app stops directly when I run it.

Comment: Can you please post the error logs - just for clarification, you placed showAFly() below the line mentioned, correct?

Comment: Yes I have done it. 
onCreate(...)
...
playSpace = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.playSpace);
        showAFly();
    }
 and I have also set the LayoutParams 
 ...
 playSpace.addView(fly,params);
 fly.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: -100 at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182) at com.code123.en.createObj.MainActivity.showAFly(MainActivity.java:39) at 

ie: randomNumber.nextInt(width- fly_width);

This is what's causing the crash. If it's less than 0, nextInt will throw an exception.


And to it, until *after* onResume() is called, your width will be 0. Hence the negative number.

Comment: Please could you tell me how I can fix it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0 - This will do a better job of explaining it than I ever could.

Comment: Thank you so much sbso, @Saikrishna R, I am going to read it.